# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p + \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^p \ge \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i+x_{i+1})^p$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

> Given $p\ge 1$, prove that for all $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\ge 0(n\ge 4)$, the following inequality holds:
> $$
>  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p  + \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^p \ge \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i+x_{i+1})^p,
> $$
> where $x_{n+1}=x_1$.

I believe that it can be proved by induction. If the inequality holds for $n$ variables,
then for $n+1$ variables, WLOG we assume $x_{n+1}=\min\limits_{1\le i\le n+1}\{x_i\}$. We only need to prove that
$$
x_{n+1}^p + (s+x_{n+1})^p - s^p \ge (x_n+x_{n+1})^p+(x_{n+1}+x_1)^p-(x_n+x_1)^p,
$$
where $s=x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$.

From the convexity of $x^p$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{n+1}^p + (s+x_{n+1})^p &\ge s^p + (2x_{n+1})^p,\\
(2x_{n+1})^p + (x_n+x_1)^p&\ge (x_n+x_{n+1})^p + (x_{n+1}+x_1)^p.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, the inequality holds for $n+1$ variables.

Note that the $n=3$ case fails when $p\in(1,2)$, we need to prove the $n=4$ case directly. But it seems to be the most difficult part. I tried to use the convexity and Jensen's inequality but failed.
Any good ideas to solve the $n=4$ case?